# Javascript: Using while loop to wait for document load not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to create an html document for my coworkers to complete an online test (I have the right answers). When the document loads, it requests your user and password and tries to log in, then fill the answers and submit.

However I can't pass the user and password values to the elements in the page, this is the error:

`Cannot set property 'value' of null`

The page is not loading completely when my script tries to get its elements, how could I make this work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BCG test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bcg(){
            var user = prompt("Enter username: ");
            var pass = prompt("Enter password: ");
            var site = "http://app.huawei.com/bcg";

            location = site;

            while(true){
                if (document.readyState == "complete"){
                    break;
                }
            }

            var user_box = document.getElementById("uid");
            var pass_box = document.getElementById("password");
            var submit_button = document.getElementsByName("Submit")[0];

            user_box.value = user;
            pass_box.value = pass;
            submit_button.click();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "bcg()">
    <h1>BCG TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot interact with content from another page like you're trying to do. When you change the `location` and begin navigation, the current page's contents including all JavaScript within it, removed from existence, before the next page loads. If you want to emulate a user, look into [headless browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a `while(true)` loop because that loops infinitely fast, forever. That will cause the browser to freeze. If you need to keep checking something, set a timer with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

However, for this purpose, it appears you want to wait until the page loads. Put your code to be executed in this block instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var user_box = document.getElementById("uid");
        var pass_box = document.getElementById("password");
        var submit_button = document.getElementsByName("Submit")[0];

        user_box.value = user;
        pass_box.value = pass;
        submit_button.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in javascript:

```
while(true){if(document.readyState == "complete"){ break; }}
```

It will never exit this event frame.

use `window.onload = function(){}` or  `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Any of these functions will be called when document loads.